# LINQ using a function inside a Where clause?

Tags: asp.net, linq, umbraco

I am trying to do this:

```
myIEnumberable = myIEnumberable 
                .Where(myFunc(moveInDate, r => r.GetPropertyAsDateTime("date")) == true);
```

But getting the error:"cannot convert lamda expression to System.Date.Datetime because it is not a delegate type.

How do I go about writing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myIEnumberable = myIEnumberable
    .Where(r => myFunc(moveInDate, r.GetPropertyAsDateTime("date")) );
```